# SD Card Appears Multiple Times in /media?

Tags: mount, sd-card, media

So I've noticed that my SD card under /media/user/ is mentioned with multiple names. It will appear as /media/user/SDCARD,/media/user/SDCARD1, /media/user/SDCARD2, and so on. Only the latest one is the mounted SD card, and the rest just sit there. This number increases over time.

Why does this happen, and is there any way to prevent it? I have a program that creates files on this card, but the constant path changes break the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just manually mount it there , first unmount the sdcard if already mounted `umount /dev/sdXy` where `X` the order the SD card was mounted and `y` is the partition number. Then you can delete all the folders inside that user directory , `rm -rf user && mkdir user/SDCARD`.Then mount it there , `mount /dev/sdXy /media/user/SDCARD`. Tada done.

Not sure why it happens though.

Cheers

Comment: Yeah, I was able to clear the fake ones, but preventing this from happening again is the big question.